# How can I make an app restart every time it is opened?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, multitasking

I have an app that lets say, shows the alphabet. Each time I start the app, I'd like it to start at the letter A.

Right now, I guess because of multi-tasking, the app starts wherever it left off.

Is there a good way to force it to start at the beginning each time?

Thanks.

Comment: Would that not break the expected behaviour of multi-tasking. Why not just add a reset button or action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a parameter to set in the Info.plist. Look for `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`

You can also setup your app delegate to handle the wake up as you want. Have a look at this http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/

Comment: Thanks for your help. It got me thinking along this line.. UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend appears to have been changed (for the better) in xCode4 / iOS4.3. The boolean is now "Application does not run in background", and - well - it works!

David